# Помогите плиз, не могу проиндексировать сайт на angularjs

Tags: .htaccess, angularjs, seo, google-search

В общем я буду описывать ситуацию, чтоб было более менее понятно что к чему.
У меня есть проект на `angularjs`, надо проиндексировать в `Google`.

Сам `Google` говорит, что если вставить в `header` сайта мета тег `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`, то поисковая машина понимает, что на сайте есть `ajax` контент и он ссылки типу `http://sitename/#!/blog/news` читает как `http://sitename?_escaped_fragment_=blog/news`.

Я сделал следующее:

1. в `angularjs`:

`Application.config(['$locationProvider',function($locationProvider){ $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!'); $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); }]);`

2. Написал мини движок, который выдает контент для `Google` по ссылке: `http://sitename/api/html?page=blog/news`.
3. В `.htaccess` перенаправляю все запросы, где есть `get` параметр `_escaped_fragment_` на api статики:

   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$ RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/html?page=%1 [NC,R=301,L]`
4. Тест на ссылки `http://sitename?_escaped_fragment_=blog/news` - все хорошо, перенаправляет на `http://sitename/api/html?page=blog/news` и показывается нужный контент.

И как бы все хорошо и все должно работать правильно, но проверяю ссылки сайта в `google.com/webmasters/tools` - и там подтягивается `html` `angularjs` проекта (тот в котором я вставил мета тег `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`), и я так понимаю, что `Google` даже не обращает внимания на `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`.

Вопрос: что я делаю не так, как мне это все исправить? может кто то с этим столкнулся, может кто то может дать совет?

Comment: я бы открыл логи на сервере и посмотрел бы, ходит лигугловый бот туда, куда нужно.

Comment: 66.249.64.180 - - [03/Oct/2016:11:53:15 +0300] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 1916 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.64.180 - - [03/Oct/2016:11:53:15 +0300] "GET /page/about-us HTTP/1.1" 200 1916 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"

Comment: Google не вставляет get параметр, я так понимаю, что он на мета тег (фрагмент) не обращает внимания

Comment: Переформулирую. Посмотрите, есть ли в логе обращение на ссылки с 4 пункта.

Comment: такого вообще в логах нет

Comment: тогда два варианта - либо оно действительно не работает, либо гугл научился парсить ангуляр. Вбейте в поиск гугла текст, который по прямой ссылке так просто не получить и посмотрите, найдет ли.

Comment: второй вариант отпадает, потому, что у меня тайтли и дескрипшин должны меняться в зависимости от страницы, а они не меняются при тесте на вебмастере(

Comment: и текст, который не доступный по прямой ссылке тоже не получает вебмастер(

Comment: я не могу понять, если это действительно не работает, то как правильно делать, чтоб оно работало, я уверен, что не только мне нужно индексировать angular проект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Год назад это все отменили [https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html](http://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) 
Ищите другие способы или пишите свой велосипед (например можете сделать генерацию страниц на `php` или `nodejs` именно для ботов, а в `.htaccess` перенаправить всех ботов на `url` этих специальных страниц)